# yii -> widget "TbActiveForm" -> delete(rename) placeholder

Tags: yii

How can i delete(rename) placeholder from(in) text input field, not changing "attributeLabels()" in models?

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('booster.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'email-recovery-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'clientOptions' => array(
            'validateOnSubmit' => true,
            'validateOnChange' => false,
        ),
        'type' => 'inline',
    ));
    ?>

    <div class="label-input" id="rec-button"><?=Yii::t('app', 'Email');?></div>
    <?=$form->textFieldGroup($model, 'email');?>
    <br/>
    <input class="yBtn" type="submit" value="<?=Yii::t('app', 'Do action');?>">

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

I tried

```
<?=$form->textFieldGroup($model, 'email', array('placeholder'=>'Username'));?>
```

but it does't work

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood correct what you want is the following:

```
echo $form->textFieldGroup($model, 'email', array('hint'=>'Username'));
```